# Some confusion with conda / pip installations of PyQt5 on my Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, package-management, python, qt, anaconda

### **Context**

I wanted to install [PyQt5](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/) in my conda base environment, along with some other libraries. I have completed this task in different sessions. The problem is that when I went in Visual Studio Code and imported all my libraries in a python file, my linter could not resolve missing imports from PyQt5 alone. I have checked that the chosen interpreter in the IDE is the one of the base environment of anaconda3. So I think I had installed PyQt5 while my conda was not active (as I had been playing with that for a while). I then installed it in my conda environment, so now everything is fine, except for the fact that I may have more than one copy of PyQt5 installed, and this is not ideal. I would like to understand what I actually have done and have stored in my Ubuntu partition, more for the sake of knowledge than for getting back some disk space.

### **Shell-based disk inspection**

I have collected some info about my installations, and I report them here in order to help you have a grasp of what is inside my Ubuntu isntallation. All the next commands have been executed while in the base conda environment.

```
$conda list | grep -e qt5 -e Qt5
pyqt5                     5.15.4                   pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5-qt5                 5.15.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5-sip                 12.8.1                   pypi_0    pypi
```

```
$pip install pyqt5
Requirement already satisfied: pyqt5 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (5.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-Qt5>=5.15 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pyqt5) (5.15.2)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.8 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pyqt5) (12.8.1)
```

```
$ dpkg --list | grep -e qt5 -e Qt5
ii  libpyside2-dev                              5.14.0-1~exp1ubuntu5                  amd64        Python bindings for Qt5 (development files)
ii  libpyside2-py3-5.14                         5.14.0-1~exp1ubuntu5                  amd64        Python 3 bindings for Qt5 (base files)
ii  libqt5concurrent5:amd64                     5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1                  amd64        Qt 5 concurrent module
ii  libqt5core5a:amd64                          5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1                  amd64        Qt 5 core module
ii  libqt5dbus5:amd64                           5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1                  amd64        Qt 5 D-Bus module
ii  libqt5designer5:amd64                       5.12.8-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Qt 5 designer module
ii  libqt5designercomponents5:amd64             5.12.8-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Qt 5 Designer components module
ii  libqt5gui5:amd64                            5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1                  amd64        Qt 5 GUI module
ii  libqt5help5:amd64                           5.12.8-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Qt 5 help module
ii  libqt5network5:amd64                        5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1                  amd64        Qt 5 network module
ii  libqt5opengl5:amd64                         5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1                  amd64        Qt 5 OpenGL module
ii  libqt5opengl5-dev:amd64                     5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1                  amd64        Qt 5 OpenGL library development files
ii  libqt5positioning5:amd64                    5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1                  amd64        Qt Positioning module
ii  libqt5printsupport5:amd64                   5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1                  amd64        Qt 5 print support module
ii  libqt5qml5:amd64                            5.12.8-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Qt 5 QML module
ii  libqt5quick5:amd64                          5.12.8-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Qt 5 Quick library
ii  libqt5quickparticles5:amd64                 5.12.8-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Qt 5 Quick particles module
ii  libqt5quickshapes5:amd64                    5.12.8-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Qt 5 Quick Shapes module
ii  libqt5quicktest5:amd64                      5.12.8-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Qt 5 Quick Test library
ii  libqt5quickwidgets5:amd64                   5.12.8-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Qt 5 Quick Widgets library
ii  libqt5sensors5:amd64                        5.12.8-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Qt Sensors module
ii  libqt5sql5:amd64                            5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1                  amd64        Qt 5 SQL module
ii  libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64                     5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1                  amd64        Qt 5 SQLite 3 database driver
ii  libqt5svg5:amd64                            5.12.8-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Qt 5 SVG module
ii  libqt5test5:amd64                           5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1                  amd64        Qt 5 test module
ii  libqt5webchannel5:amd64                     5.12.8-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Web communication library for Qt
ii  libqt5webkit5:amd64                         5.212.0~alpha4-1ubuntu2               amd64        Web content engine library for Qt
ii  libqt5webkit5-dev:amd64                     5.212.0~alpha4-1ubuntu2               amd64        Web content engine library for Qt - development files
ii  libqt5widgets5:amd64                        5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1                  amd64        Qt 5 widgets module
ii  libqt5x11extras5:amd64                      5.12.8-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Qt 5 X11 extras
ii  libqt5xml5:amd64                            5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1                  amd64        Qt 5 XML module
ii  libqwt-qt5-6                                6.1.4-1.1build1                       amd64        Qt widgets library for technical applications (runtime, qt5)
ii  libqwt-qt5-dev                              6.1.4-1.1build1                       amd64        Qt widgets library for technical applications (development, qt5)
ii  pyqt5-dev                                   5.14.1+dfsg-3build1                   all          Development files for PyQt5
ii  python3-pyqt5                               5.14.1+dfsg-3build1                   amd64        Python 3 bindings for Qt5
ii  python3-pyqt5.qtopengl                      5.14.1+dfsg-3build1                   amd64        Python 3 bindings for Qt5's OpenGL module
ii  python3-pyqt5.qtsvg                         5.14.1+dfsg-3build1                   amd64        Python 3 bindings for Qt5's SVG module
ii  python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit                      5.14.1+dfsg-3build1                   amd64        Python 3 bindings for Qt5's WebKit module
ii  python3-pyside2.qtcore                      5.14.0-1~exp1ubuntu5                  amd64        Python bindings for Qt5 core module (Python 3)
ii  python3-pyside2.qtgui                       5.14.0-1~exp1ubuntu5                  amd64        Python bindings for Qt5 Gui module (Python 3)
ii  python3-pyside2.qtsvg                       5.14.0-1~exp1ubuntu5                  amd64        Python bindings for Qt5 Svg module (Python 3)
ii  python3-pyside2.qtwidgets                   5.14.0-1~exp1ubuntu5                  amd64        Python bindings for Qt5 Widgets module (Python 3)
ii  qdoc-qt5                                    5.12.8-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Qt 5 qdoc tool
ii  qhelpgenerator-qt5                          5.12.8-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Qt 5 qhelpgenerator tool
ii  qt5-assistant                               5.12.8-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Qt 5 Assistant
ii  qt5-gtk-platformtheme:amd64                 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1                  amd64        Qt 5 GTK+ 3 platform theme
ii  qt5-qmake:amd64                             5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1                  amd64        Qt 5 qmake Makefile generator tool
ii  qt5-qmake-bin                               5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1                  amd64        Qt 5 qmake Makefile generator tool — binary file
ii  qt5-qmltooling-plugins:amd64                5.12.8-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Qt 5 qmltooling plugins
ii  qtattributionsscanner-qt5                   5.12.8-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Qt 5 qtattributionsscanner tool
```

Sorry for the not-so-precise `grep`, but I am not that good with it. Furthermore, I suspect I have even more Qt stuff as, as I just discovered, there are some Qt entries in my apps list, and I do not think they come in the system by default, nor they are strictly python-related. Maybe they are listed in `dpkg --list | grep -e qt5 -e Qt5`, but I cannot undestand it. I also attach part of my shell history, in case it helps better understanding what I have done:

```
$ history | grep -e qt5 -e Qt5
 1795  conda install PyQt5
 1796  pip install PyQt5
 1799  pip remove PyQt5
 1800  pip uninstall PyQt5
 1805  sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
 1855  conda install PyQt5
 1877  conda install pyqt5
 1881  pip uninstall pyqt5
 1885  conda uninstall PyQt5
 1892  pip install PyQt5
 1938  pip install pyqt5
 1939  pip install PyQt5
```

from which I removed all the unnecessary commands (e.g. `history` ones). Anyway, I think I was at 1797-1798 in terms of history commands when my Python in the base conda environment could not see the Qt5 library (see previous section)

### **What I want**

It is clear that I am not fully understanding what I am doing, so I would like to receive some insights. I would also like to better understand how to determine if a package listed in `dpkg` or in `conda` is actually just a portion of another, like for example all the above instances of `pyqt5-sip`, as I am 100% sure of never have written "sip" in my terminal.


Thank you!